# How to debug "Mixed Content" errors in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, error-handling

I'm working on a project in codepen (it is large project for me as a beginner). So I decided to clean it up a little bit in https://www.dirtymarkup.com/ and pasted tidied code back in codepen. However after that procedure my code is broken and displays a bunch of errors in console.log. If you need look at console.

[Project on codepen](https://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

**HTML**

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--********** HEADER **********-->

    <header class="navigation">
        <div class="icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" onclick=
            "openNav()"></span>
            <div id="headerText">
                Social Media
            </div>
        </div><!--icon div-->
        <div id="textRandomQuote">
            Random Quote Project 2016 <span id="by">by</span> <span id=
            "nzMai">NZ MAI</span>
        </div>
    </header><!--********** QUOTE SECTION **********-->
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 quoteDiv col-xs-12">
                    <p id="quotes"></p><!--end of "quotes" p-->
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" id="getQuote" type=
                    "button">Get Quote</button>
                    <div class="like&share pull-right">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart social-but"
                        data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title=
                        "Like the Quote"></span> <span class=
                        "glyphicon glyphicon-share" data-placement="left"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share the Quote"></span>
                        <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter"
                        data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title=
                        "Tweet the Quote"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" div-->
            </div><!--row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class=
                "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12 bioDivContainer">
                    <h1 class="authorName"></h1>
                    <p class="bioDiv"></p>
                </div>
            </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--end of container-->
    </section>
    <section class="articlesSection">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="wikiArticlesDiv">
                    <h1 class="wikiArticlesHeader"></h1>
                    <ul class="wikiArticlesList"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!--SIDE NAVIGATION-->
    <div class="sidenav" id="mySidenav">
        <a class="closebtn" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=
        "closeNav()">&times;</a> <a href="#">About</a> <a href="#"><img alt=
        "twitter" id="twitter" src=
        "https://www.socialflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/twitter1.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img alt="youtube" id="youtube" src=
        "https://worldartsme.com/images/youtube-icon-clipart-1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img alt="facebook" id="facebook" src=
        "https://rocketfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Buy-facebook-likes.png">
        </a>
    </div><!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
    <!-- Add all page content inside this div if you want the side nav to push page content to the right (not used if you only want the sidenav to sit on top of the page -->
```

**CSS**

```
@import  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto;

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #e0f2f1;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 16px #aec0bf;
}

.icon {
    display: inline;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
}

.glyphicon-align-justify {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#headerText {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: .9;
    color: #424242;
}

#textRandomQuote {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: .75;
}

#by {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    opacity: .4;
}

#nzMai {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #424242;
    padding: 10px;
}

.quoteDiv {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,transparent 50%,#F5F5F5 50%,#F5F5F5),repeating-linear-gradient(180deg,transparent,transparent 50%,#F5F5F5 50%,#F5F5F5),repeating-radial-gradient(circle,#607D8B,#607D8B 45%,transparent 45%,transparent 60%,#607D8B 60%,#607D8B 100%);
    background-size: 3px 3px;
}

.quoteDiv:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,transparent,transparent 50%,#9E9E9E 50%,#9E9E9E),repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent,transparent 50%,#424242 50%,#424242);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}

#quotes {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #FAFAFA;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

#getQuote {
    text-align: center;
}

.bioDivContainer {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #ebf9fe;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    opacity: .9;
    color: #424242;
}

.bioDiv {
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    opacity: .9;
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.articlesSection {
    margin-top: 45px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e0f2f1;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 16px #aec0bf;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#wikiArticlesDiv {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: .9;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.wikiArticlesHeader {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    opacity: .9;
    color: #424242;
}

.wikiArticlesList {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.articleItem {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    opacity: .8;
}

.shortInfo {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: .8;
}

.glyphicon-heart,.glyphicon-share,.fa-twitter {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #337ab7;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .8;
}

.active {
    color: red;
    opacity: .8;
}

/**********SIDE NAVIGATION****************/
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
/* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0;
/* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed;
/* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
/* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
/* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px;
/* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: .5s;
/* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: .3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover,.offcanvas a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

a #twitter {
    width: 60px;
}

a #youtube {
    width: 60px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

a #facebook {
    width: 60px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #wikiArticlesDiv {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .wikiArticlesHeader {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .authorName {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    #quotes {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .shortInfo {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .bioDiv {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    #by,#nzMai {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var randomQuoteGenerator = (function() {
    //var foundArticle = "Ben Stein"; 
    //////////
    ///General
    //////////
    var general = {
        // The URL to the quote API
        url: 'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/',
        // What to display as the author name if s/he's unknown
        unknownAuthor: 'Unknown',
        // Base URL for the tweet links generation
        tweetURL: 'https://twitter.com/home?status=',
        //wikiURL:'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + foundArticle + '&format=json&callback=wikiCalback'
    };
    ///////////// 
    ////DOM cache
    /////////////
    var domCache = {
        $quoteDiv: $('#quotes'),
        $authorDiv: $('#author'),
        $clickButton: $('#getQuote'),
        $tweetButton: $('#tweetQuote'),
        $bioDiv: $('.bioDiv'),
        $authorName: $('.authorName'),
        $wikiArticlesDivHeader: $('.wikiArticlesHeader'),
        $wikiArticlesList: $('.wikiArticlesList'),
        $wikiArticlesDiv: $('#wikiArticlesDiv')
    };
    var getWikiAuthorBio = function(author) {
            var url =
                'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' +
                author + '&format=json&callback=wikiCalback'
                //////////////
                //Wiki request
                /////////////
            var wikirequest = function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(wikiData) {
                                // Fetch the biographical information
                                var bioName = wikiData[2][0];
                                // Check if instead of bio there is a phrase "The article may refer to...." if so then change indices
                                if (bioName.indexOf(
                                    'may refer to') >= 0) {
                                    bioName = wikiData[2][1];
                                } else {
                                    var bioName = wikiData[2][0];
                                }
                                var wikiArcticles = wikiData[1];
                                var wikiArticlesShortInfo =
                                    wikiData[2]
                                domCache.$wikiArticlesList.html(
                                    '');
                                var authorName = wikiData[0];
                                if (authorName === "Unknown") {
                                    console.log(
                                        "This is author's name " +
                                        authorName);
                                    $('.bioDiv').html('');
                                    $('.bioDiv').text(
                                        'No available information'
                                    );
                                }
                                for (var j = 0; j < wikiData.length; j++) {
                                    var articleAuthor =
                                        wikiData[1][j];
                                    var articleInfo = wikiData[
                                        2][j];
                                    var linkAuthor = wikiData[3]
                                        [j];
                                    domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append(
                                        '<li class="articleItem">' +
                                        '<span>' +
                                        '<a href =' +
                                        linkAuthor +
                                        ' target="_blank" >' +
                                        articleAuthor +
                                        '</a>' + '</span>' +
                                        '<span class="shortInfo">' +
                                        articleInfo +
                                        '</span>' + '</li>'
                                    );
                                    // Check if some articles are undefined if so hide them
                                    if (typeof articleAuthor ===
                                        "undefined") {
                                        $('.articleItem').last()
                                            .html('');
                                    }
                                    if (articleInfo === "") {
                                        $('.shortInfo').last().html(
                                            '');
                                    }
                                    //console.log(j + " " + articleAuthor);
                                    //console.log(j + " " + articleInfo);
                                    //console.log(j + " " + linkAuthor);
                                } // end of for loop
                                // Short biography
                                console.log(wikiData);
                                console.log(wikiArcticles);
                                console.log(url);
                                domCache.$bioDiv.text(bioName);
                            } // end of success
                    });
                } // wikirequest
            wikirequest();
        }
        ///////////////////////////////
        //Display the quote on the page
        ///////////////////////////////
    var displayQuote = function(quote, author) {
        domCache.$quoteDiv.text(quote);
        domCache.$authorDiv.text(author);
        domCache.$authorName.text(author);
        domCache.$bioDiv.text(getWikiAuthorBio(author));
    };
    //////////
    //getQuote
    /////////
    var getQuote = function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: general.url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: "saveQuote",
                data: 'method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=saveQuote',
                success: function(data) {
                        if (!data.quoteAuthor) {
                            data.quoteAuthor = general.unknownAuthor;
                        }
                        var quote = data.quoteText;
                        var author = data.quoteAuthor;
                        displayQuote(quote, author);
                        var addon =
                            "'s Related Wikipedia Articles";
                        domCache.$wikiArticlesDivHeader.text(
                            author + addon)
                        console.log(data);
                    } // end of success
            });
        } // get quote
        ////////////////////////////
        //get new quote by clicking
        ///////////////////////////
    var ul = function() {
        domCache.$clickButton.on('click', getQuote);
        domCache.$wikiArticlesList.html("");
    };
    var init = function() {
        // Display a quote
        getQuote();
        ul();
    };
    return {
        init: init
    };
})(); // end of self-invoking function "randomQuoteGenerator"
//////////
//function is ready
///////////
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize the QuoteGenerator module
    randomQuoteGenerator.init();
});
// SIDE NAVIGATION
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */

function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */

function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
$(".social-but").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Errors in console

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.socialflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/twitter1.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://worldartsme.com/images/youtube-icon-clipart-1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?callback=saveQuote&method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=saveQuote&_=1470391383459'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`Z` and undo?

Comment: the errors are self explanatory ... you're loading http:// in a https:// page

Comment: Please remove http: . example use like this  "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

Comment: From all references and links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console errors you are receiving are exactly what they say they are, Mixed Content errors. You are loading the codepen page via HTTPS but the resources named in the errors are being loaded over HTTP. You can either change the URLs for those resources to HTTPS urls (alter http:// to https:// ) or remove the protocol designations entirely enabling the browser to pick which protocol to use ( remove http: leaving just the // ).

Comment: @NZMAI is there an issue besides the console errors you can call out for our attention? The answer I provided addresses the console errors directly but without more information as to what is screwed up in codepen (or your old code to compare output against if you still have access to it) there's not much anyone can do to help.

Comment: @NZMAI okay, any specific issues you'd care to call out so that we can assist with them directly?

Comment: It seems that the problem is with API provider. Thanks for help!

Comment: @NZMAI No problem, if the information provided in my answer was helpful in determining the solution to your log issues and discovering the API provider issue marking it as the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120230/discussion-between-nzmai-and-j-bartus).